# How to remove a CNAME record?

Tags: localhost, hosts, cname

I use the hostname `basic.localmachine.io` for local development and it points to the localhost. For some reason, `basic.localmachine.io` has a CNAME set in my machine to 
`basic.wpengine.com`. I have no idea how that happened, and I would like to remove it.

### dig output for basic.localmachine.io

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> basic.localmachine.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36219
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;basic.localmachine.io.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
basic.localmachine.io.      0   IN  CNAME   basic.wpengine.com.
basic.wpengine.com. 300 IN  A   50.116.58.222

;; Query time: 403 msec
;; SERVER: xx.xxx.xxx.xx#xx(xx.xxx.xxx.xx)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep  6 13:18:34 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 78
```

### dig output for localmachine.io

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> localmachine.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34838
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localmachine.io.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localmachine.io.        3600    IN  A   198.74.57.83

;; Query time: 759 msec
;; SERVER: xx.xxx.xxx.xx#xx(xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep  6 14:18:07 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

### /etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost localmachine localmachine.io basic.localmachine.com basic.localmachine.io advanced.localmachine.io basic.localmachine.io sentry.localmachine.io slanger.localmachine.io
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)

Comment: Have you got access to the DNS zone?

Comment: @BenLavender  Where are the DNS Zone files located?